# How to write eloquent query for MariaDB system versioning?

Tags: laravel

I am trying to write an eloquent query to get system versioned data from MariaDB table.

Here is my code:

```
$addressHistory = DB::select("
  SELECT * FROM addresses FOR SYSTEM_TIME ALL WHERE id = $id
");
```

The above approach is not the best way so, I want to write the above query by using methods provided by eloquent.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem and for me it worked by adding a QueryBuilder macro:

```
\Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::macro("bySystemTime", function(string $timestamp = null) {
  $timestamp = $timestamp ? "AS OF TIMESTAMP '$timestamp'" : 'ALL';
  $this->from = \DB::raw("`$this->from` FOR SYSTEM_TIME $timestamp");
  return $this;
});
```

This is not the best way, might be ugly, but it currently works as expected...
The following selects the data as of this date:

```
\App\Model\Person::bySystemTime('2021-12-06 17:14:00')->get();
```

The following will return the first version made, because if you use SYSTEM_TIME ALL, all Versions will return in the order being made/inserted:

```
\App\Model\Person::bySystemTime()->find(3);
```

Not that if you are using `with()`, the following will return the current data state:

```
dd(\App\Model\Human::with('Person')->whereHas('Person', function($Q) {
  $Q->bySystemTime('2021-12-06 16:25:00');
})->get()->toArray());
```

If you want to get the Person versioned, you must pass in the same method in the with call:

```
$Q = function($Q) {
  $Q->bySystemTime('2021-12-06 16:25:00');
};
dd(\App\Model\Human::with(['Person' => $Q])->whereHas('Person', $Q)->get()->toArray());
```

It cannot guarantee that this will work in all situations, i havent tried that enough, but my first view on that is successfully.

Answer (score -2):

First of all, You will have to create a model for the "Addresses" and use the below query. You can add multiple where conditions in it.

```
$addressHistory = Addresses::where('id', $id)->first();
```

To retrieve all records:

```
$addressHistory = Addresses::all();
```

Retrieving A Record By Primary Key:

```
$addressHistory = Addresses::find($id);
```

Comment: I wanted to convert the above sql into eloquent query, your answer is right but missing one thing "SYSTEM_TIME ALL"